# Is it grammatical to say "effects of children's lives getting boring"?

Tags: grammar, gerunds

Now, I am not just concerned about whether it's right or wrong. I have studied some grammar structures that are similar:
"there have been reports of tourists getting angry after their hats got stolen",

"those harmful effects are as a result of children's lives getting boring",

"my dad is worried about my life becoming boring at an old age".

I mostly used the same verb to create emphasis.

The main question is the last 3 sentences, which I think are grammatical,  have the same pattern with the the first one -- of+ noun + gerund, or maybe, of +  noun + supporting verb + adjective -- so if the 1st sentence is wrong (I am just assuming it is; not sure yet), why are those ones correct?

Comment: Proofreading is off-topic, but may I suggest "...effects are _the_ result..."

Comment: It helps if you can provide a complete sentence. It's not a good piece of writing, but it's grammatical as far as it goes (obviously the rest of the sentence could render it ungrammatical). Part of the problem is that from the extract you give, it's not clear if it is the effects or the lives that are getting boring. Also, "getting" has a lot of meanings and uses, so it's less ambiguous to use a less ambiguous word, maybe "becoming".

Comment: @StuartF "There is a tendency for people to underestimate the effects of children's lives getting boring, but when that happens, their mental wellbeing suffers.

Answer (score 1):

There is no error and you could create a sentence such as

> Bad behaviour and a lack of respect are some of the effects of children's lives getting boring.